# How to break long text lines in Doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

In Doxygen formatted comments, I know that I can add a `\n` or `<br>` to break lines, but my requirement is a bit different.

I have some function descriptions which have quite some text in them, and the function itself has *many* dependencies in a `dot` graph. The latter results in a wide enough browseable graph, but that forces also description **text lines** to be that wide.
The resulting HTML is then forcing me to scroll horizontally even to read descriptions.

Is there any *common simple solution* to it? 
Basically, I would like to have a *reduced* width for the function description, no matter how wide is any following interactive `dot` graph...

[EDIT]

Note that for clarity I reduced `MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH` from the unlimited 0 value to a more manageable **3**. 
This measure limited my graphs to not run wildly in width, however, it would be nice to know whether there is any other *good practice*.

[EDIT]

Adding a clarification image [image] of the result with default `DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES` (set to 50) and `MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH` (set to 0), viewing the HTML of a function with a resulting wide graph and overflowing text as well, given the limited right margin of the browser.

I don't blame doxygen or dot for the behavior, just wondering if is there any solution that lets me scroll for the image, but at the same time limits text extent to viewable width.

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Which version of dot? Please add, the source of,  a small example that shows the problem (including the settings different from the default settings i.e. the result  of `doxygen -x Doxyfile`). Also add an image showing the problem in the output.

Comment: @albert currently running the latest doxygen 1.9.7 and graphviz/dot 7.1.0, though it's not any *unexpected behavior*, I'm sure that even any release ten years older would do the same: the calling graph/image needs space and container HTML/`div` is expanded in width, that's normal. My problem is that the description text is in the same `div` of the image AFAIK. Unfortunately, I have no permission to share any part of this code, let's see if I can do anything else to show.

Comment: For propriety software it is hard to share but an example with "lorem ipsum" text and function names like `fie1` ... would do. Did you have a look at the settings `DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT=svg` and `INTERACTIVE_SVG=YES`

Comment: @albert that's really interesting: SVG is scaled, then it lets text fill up space. **Very good solution**, if it wasn't in a comment! :^D

Comment: @albert I conducted some tests, and so far it's a **solution**, with a couple of drawbacks. First, with a complex module the interaction is very slow (click on a function, wait..., here's the container window, wait..., here's the full page rendered). Second, the mouse pointer interaction is an over-sensitive blinking crazy mosquito (on a crowded itty-bitty tiny graph)